# Cannot use my compiled single file component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, browserify

Okay so I'm trying my hands at templating using single file components using vue.js but I have to admit I'm stuck. So far, here's what I have:

**Hello.vue:**

```
<template>
<p>{{ greeting }} World!!</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function(){
            return {
                greeting: 'Hello'
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    p {
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

**main.js**

```
import Hello from './hello.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: function(h) {return h(Hello); }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="js/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="build/hello.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "un test",
  "main": "hello.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.14",
    "vueify": "^9.4.1"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      "vueify",
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "./js/vue.js": "vue",
    "vue": "global:Vue"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "tobbi filteau",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {}
}
```

**hello.js**

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var Vue // late bind
var version
var map = window.__VUE_HOT_MAP__ = Object.create(null)
var installed = false
var isBrowserify = false
var initHookName = 'beforeCreate'

exports.install = function (vue, browserify) {
  if (installed) return
  installed = true

  Vue = vue.__esModule ? vue.default : vue
  version = Vue.version.split('.').map(Number)
  isBrowserify = browserify

  // compat with < 2.0.0-alpha.7
  if (Vue.config._lifecycleHooks.indexOf('init') > -1) {
    initHookName = 'init'
  }

  exports.compatible = version[0] >= 2
  if (!exports.compatible) {
    console.warn(
      '[HMR] You are using a version of vue-hot-reload-api that is ' +
      'only compatible with Vue.js core ^2.0.0.'
    )
    return
  }
}

/**
 * Create a record for a hot module, which keeps track of its constructor
 * and instances
 *
 * @param {String} id
 * @param {Object} options
 */

exports.createRecord = function (id, options) {
  var Ctor = null
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    Ctor = options
    options = Ctor.options
  }
  makeOptionsHot(id, options)
  map[id] = {
    Ctor: Vue.extend(options),
    instances: []
  }
}

/**
 * Make a Component options object hot.
 *
 * @param {String} id
 * @param {Object} options
 */

function makeOptionsHot (id, options) {
  injectHook(options, initHookName, function () {
    map[id].instances.push(this)
  })
  injectHook(options, 'beforeDestroy', function () {
    var instances = map[id].instances
    instances.splice(instances.indexOf(this), 1)
  })
}

/**
 * Inject a hook to a hot reloadable component so that
 * we can keep track of it.
 *
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {String} name
 * @param {Function} hook
 */

function injectHook (options, name, hook) {
  var existing = options[name]
  options[name] = existing
    ? Array.isArray(existing)
      ? existing.concat(hook)
      : [existing, hook]
    : [hook]
}

function tryWrap (fn) {
  return function (id, arg) {
    try { fn(id, arg) } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
      console.warn('Something went wrong during Vue component hot-reload. Full reload required.')
    }
  }
}

exports.rerender = tryWrap(function (id, options) {
  var record = map[id]
  if (!options) {
    record.instances.slice().forEach(function (instance) {
      instance.$forceUpdate()
    })
    return
  }
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    options = options.options
  }
  record.Ctor.options.render = options.render
  record.Ctor.options.staticRenderFns = options.staticRenderFns
  record.instances.slice().forEach(function (instance) {
    instance.$options.render = options.render
    instance.$options.staticRenderFns = options.staticRenderFns
    instance._staticTrees = [] // reset static trees
    instance.$forceUpdate()
  })
})

exports.reload = tryWrap(function (id, options) {
  var record = map[id]
  if (options) {
    if (typeof options === 'function') {
      options = options.options
    }
    makeOptionsHot(id, options)
    if (version[1] < 2) {
      // preserve pre 2.2 behavior for global mixin handling
      record.Ctor.extendOptions = options
    }
    var newCtor = record.Ctor.super.extend(options)
    record.Ctor.options = newCtor.options
    record.Ctor.cid = newCtor.cid
    record.Ctor.prototype = newCtor.prototype
    if (newCtor.release) {
      // temporary global mixin strategy used in < 2.0.0-alpha.6
      newCtor.release()
    }
  }
  record.instances.slice().forEach(function (instance) {
    if (instance.$vnode && instance.$vnode.context) {
      instance.$vnode.context.$forceUpdate()
    } else {
      console.warn('Root or manually mounted instance modified. Full reload required.')
    }
  })
})

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
(function (global){
var __vue__options__ = (typeof module.exports === "function"? module.exports.options: module.exports)
if (module.hot) {(function () {  var hotAPI = require("vue-hot-reload-api")
  hotAPI.install((typeof window !== "undefined" ? window['Vue'] : typeof global !== "undefined" ? global['Vue'] : null), true)
  if (!hotAPI.compatible) return
  module.hot.accept()
  if (!module.hot.data) {
    hotAPI.createRecord("data-v-af3c7d92", __vue__options__)
  } else {
    hotAPI.reload("data-v-af3c7d92", __vue__options__)
  }
})()}
}).call(this,typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {})
},{"vue-hot-reload-api":1}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

var _hello = require('./hello.vue');

var _hello2 = _interopRequireDefault(_hello);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: function render(h) {
    return h(_hello2.default);
  }
});

},{"./hello.vue":2}]},{},[3]);
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is basically compile my component using this command:

browserify -t vueify -e src/main.js -o build/hello.js

Now, the command works without giving me any error... but when I try to preview the page in a browser, I get the following message in the console:

> Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've searched around quite a lot, but I haven't been able to find out what could be causing my problem so far.

EDIT: Added the compiled file and changed my render syntax a bit, but the error is still there. What bothers me is that I can see the render function inside the compiled file despite my browser telling me it's not there.

Comment: 1. Don't use arrow functions for the render function, write `render(h) { return h(Hello); }` instead. 2. If this does not fix the problem, could you share the compiled file into a pastebin?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I compiled your project with the same settings as you and I obtained a perfectly working script: https://pastebin.com/dG8FgsMh

Comment: There's no problem with the compilation. The error is in the browser when I try to load the `index.html` page.

Comment: @Cobalt Your file works indeed perfectly. Though I'm no closer to figuring out why mine doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after spending about a day pulling my hair out, I finally figured out what was going on. The problem ended up being... ***in my compilation command!!!***

Here's what I was doing:

> browserify -t vueify -e src/main.js -o build/hello.js

HOWEVER, in the package.json file, I was specifying this:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      "vueify", //Hey, aren't I already in the compilation command?
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
```

You'll notice that all of the necessary transformations are *already defined*. So this makes the `-t vueify` option in the compilation command error out because the code gets "vueified" twice, resulting in all sort of strange errors, including the one that's been bugging me out. So in the end, the only thing that needed to be done was:

> browserify -e src/main.js -o build/hello.js

I hope this helps someone in the future.